# Probability of picking multiple balls from a bag

Tags: probability, statistics, balls-in-bins

I have a bag that contains numbered balls:

- Gray balls numbered 1-13
- Green balls numbered 1-13
- Blue balls numbered 1-12
- Purple balls numbered 1-12
- Yellow balls numbered 1-8

Each color of ball has a certain chance of being pulled, lets say:

- Gray: 16%
- Green: 20%
- Blue: 35%
- Purple: 15%
- Yellow 4%

There are multiple copies of each color-number ball in the bag:

- Gray: 29 copies
- Green: 22 copies
- Blue: 18 copies
- Purple: 12 copies
- Yellow 10 copies

For example, this means there are 29 gray number 1 balls, 29 gray number 2 balls, 22 green number 1 balls, etc.

I am looking to be able to calculate the odds of picking a certain number of specific color-number balls for any number of given picks from the bag where you take 5 out at a time, if you get the color-number ball you are looking for, take it out but then replace all of the wrong balls.

For example, the odds of picking 9 purple number 1 balls in 100 attempts. Or picking 3 purple number 1 balls in 100 attempts if 6 purple number 1 balls are already removed.

This probability problem is for calculating the odds of rolling certain units in Teamfight Tactics if you are familiar with the game. Pretty complicated problem to me but maybe not to some of you.

Comment: the rules are not clear.  Are you saying that you first select a color (with the given probabilities) and then, within that color, you select a ball?  Or are you saying that, given the number of balls of each color, the stated numbers are the probabilities for each color assuming you just just uniformly at random among the balls?

Comment: You speak about choosing in blocks of $5$ subject to a particular target.  Edit your post to write that out in detail.  Suppose my goal is to get three yellow #1's and that I have two tries to get there.  What exactly do I do?

Comment: You pick 5 balls at a time, there are 13 different "kinds" of gray balls, numbered 1 through 13, and there are 29 copies of each of those in the bag. So 29 gray number 1 balls, 29 gray number 2 balls, etc. This goes for each color of ball. The probability of picking a color is given and is equal for all numbered balls of that same color. And as it relates to my specific problem, each time you pick 5 balls, the color would first be selected for each ball and then the number for the ball would be chosen.

Comment: Again, edit your post to include the details.  It's really not obvious.  And just to see if I have the the rules right, the probability that a single ball is a yellow $\#1$ is $.04\times .125=.005$, right?

Comment: Choosing in blocks of 5 is specific to the game I am trying to simulate here, you have a shop with 5 units (balls) and you can refresh the shop and see 5 new units(balls). If you wanted to get three yellow #1's with two tries, you would see 10 balls total, in two groups of 5 balls.

Comment: Yes that would be the correct probability for a single yellow #1 ball if you choose 1 ball at a time, but I believe since you see 5 balls at a time it would be .04 x .125 x 5

Comment: Oh, no.  For five balls drawn sequentially, you need to take into account that the pool changes.  To get at least one yellow $\#1$ you can note that the alternative is to never draw such a ball.  In that case, the pool does not change and you get $(1-.005)^5$ so the probability of getting at least one yellow $\#1$ is $1-.995^5\approx .02475$

Comment: A problem is that your *"Each color of ball has a certain chance of being pulled"* applies to pulling one ball but does not describe what happens when pulling five.  The Wikipedia article on [noncentral hypergeometric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_hypergeometric_distributions) describes two approaches to this kind of issue.  Once you have decided how this works, you may find simulation gets you a good enough answer faster than calculation.